# Conditionally Required Fields MS Access

Tags: database, vba, validation, ms-access-2010

I have been digging for answers on this all day and I can't seem to find a good answer. I am no good with VBA and I am certain there is a solution to my problem if I could figure out how to use VBA, but for now I am hopeful there is a simpler solution.

I have a lookup field called Incidents.Incident Type and a few other fields that I want to be populated on the same table when the Incidents.Incident Type field is equal to a certain value.

I have tried within the table properties, variations of

```
([Incident Type] In ("Value")) Or ([Required Field] Is Not Null)
```

but this trips an error.

```
The multi-valued field " cannot be used in a WHERE or HAVING clause.
```

Any thoughts about this? I am desperate at this point lol

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is light on information.  It appears you have selected a multi-valued field based on the error message and that is typically not recommended.  Here is a link that provides further explanation on the topic:

[Multivalued Fields a Good Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461582/multivalued-fields-a-good-idea)

Assuming that Incident Type is stored as text (single value), you can accomplish what you are looking for by using a validation rule.  The following will require that the required field be populated for Value1 and Value3 incidents:

```
[Incident Type] NOT IN ('Value1', 'Value3') OR [Required Field] IS NOT NULL
```