# Beginner in access db. Relationships to track records of entities

Tags: ms-access, relational-database

I am trying to set up a basic Student's database in access. The main tables that I am using are **Courses**, **Students**, **Staff** and **Modules**.

Just to clarify a bit about my terminology:

- My course is actually a University. (i.e. Economics Course)
- My Modules are the actual courses referring to each University. (i,e, Economics Course include modules such as Maths, Statistics, Econometrics etc.).
- My Staff are the teachers.
- A module includes exactly 12 lectures.
- A module is being offered in a specific semester(6 month period), A=Sept-Feb and B=Mar-Aug. One module can be offered only in one out of two semesters.

The relationships that I want to use are:

1. A course has many students. (***one-to-many***)
2. A course has many modules. (***one-to-many***)
3. Maximum 1 staff member can lead 1 course. I need to know the date he got leadership of this course (mgrstartdate). (***one-to-one***)
   Staff can have only 1 specialization (i.e. John Smith is Mathematician)
   Staff can have many qualifications (i.e. "10 years previous experience" and         "published articles")
4. A staff member teaches many modules. (***one-to-many***)
5. A student can register(undertake) in many modules. (***many-to-many***)
   In this case i need to know date of registration and the final grade(performance).
6. A student can attend many modules. (***many-to-many***)
   In this case i need to get attendance date, attendance(yes/no) and time of arrival. (Time of arrival is the reason i am tracking attendance and not absence)
7. A module includes 12 lectures. (***one-to-many***)
   A module is being offered in a specific semester(6 month period),
   A =Sept-Feb and B=Mar-Aug. One module can be offered only in one out of two semesters.

So here follows my tables and their relationships preview:
[Access Relationships preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mwJI.png)

Does it look like as described on the relationships above?
Is it functional to record student's performance, attendance and arrival time?
I used Lecture table to keep track date/time for each module. Is that needed or i can just move all the attributed of lecture table into the module table?

Answer (score 0):

Looks mostly good to me.

> 4. A staff member teaches many modules. (one-to-many)

It would surprise me if every module can only be teached by exactly one teacher. Shouldn't this be many-to-many?

I would attach `Attends` to `Lecture` instead of `Module`. Then you don't need the date again, and can compare Arrivaltime with l_time.
Although I doubt the practicality of that table. Is really someone going to record all attendances in such detail?

Are the indented fields in `Module` and `Staff` multi-valued fields? Most people advise against using them, e.g. [Multivalued Fields a Good Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461582/multivalued-fields-a-good-idea) . Better put these into additional tables with one-to-many relations.

Comment: Apparently, the relationship staff-module is many-to-many.

However i will probably do what you said about attaching Attends to Lecture, In Lecture i have already replaced dateattended-attendance-arrival time with just 1 entry of date/time type and formal general type.

The only multi-valued fields are specializations and qualifications that i already track them in separated tables.

My current problem as i was entering data with this model it seems to be an integrity issue.

Comment: My current problem as i was entering data with this model it seems to be an integrity issue.

-I registered students in  courses. (Course-Student: one-to-many)
-I registered modules in courses  (Module - Course: one-to-many)
-But when i am going to register modules on student it allows me to make any combinations without restrictions from the previous relationships. (Student-Module: many-to-many)

Any clue why this is happening? It should be against my integrity rules although i use lookup for std_matericNo and m_code in table Undertakes.

Comment: With the current rules, there is no reason for the database to prevent that. If you want to enforce it, you must add `c_title` to Undertakes and both joins. Or do it in the frontend, by only listing modules with the same `c_title` as the current student.

Comment: Add c_title as a third "primary key" on table undertakes and attach it with course? In Students and Modules table already exists and is attached.