# Multi-valued…cannot be used in a WHERE or HAVING

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I got this problem:

> Run-time error '3831': The Multi-valued field '[Type]' cannot be used on a WHERE or HAVING clause

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub Command379_Click       
    Dim strsearch as String 
    Dim strText as String

    strText = Me.TxtSearch.Value
    strsearch = "Select * from qryInfo where (([Supplier Name] LIKE ""*" & strText & "*"") OR ([Type] LIKE ""*" & strText & "*""))"

    Me.RecordSource = strsearch
End Sub
```

`[Type]` consists of a multi-valued list.

I tried to put `[Type].Value` but it didn't work too. It returned this message instead:

> Runtime error 3126. Invalid bracketing of name '[qryInfo].[tblGeneralInfo].[Supplier Name]'

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this please?

Comment: The .Value should work. Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6F64F92D-659F-411C-9503-B6624E1E323A#bm4_6

Comment: In the long run, the way to fix this is to not use MVF. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461582/multivalued-fields-a-good-idea -- http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Multi-Fields-Evils-Lo-t1991337.html

Comment: Also Type is a reserved word, so not a good choice.

Comment: @June7 For some reason, the .Value didn't even work for me. I got this message:Invalid bracketing of name '[qryInfo].[tblGeneralInfo].[Supplier Name]'

Comment: if `[Type].Value` isn't working the problem maybe in how `qryInfo` is generated. Provide the SQL code for that as well as the structure of the original table(s).

Comment: I just tested and .Value works. The error message you show is odd because [tblGeneralInfo] is not in the SQL statement. Did you test this SQL in Access query object? Use literal text in place of the variables to test.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need any parentheses in `SQL` statement. You can try following

```
strsearch = "SELECT * FROM [qryInfo] WHERE [Supplier Name] LIKE '*" & strText & "*' OR [Type] LIKE '*" & strText & "*'"
```

Comment: Removing parentheses won't make a difference. Issue is [Type] is a multi-value field.