# VBA: Accessing Variant/String Array value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would appreciate any assistance.  I am trying to access the value highlighted in my picture. The following do not work:

```
rs.items(1).value
rs.items(1).value(0)
rs.items(1).value(0).text
rs.items(1).value.value(0)
```

In some cases I receive "Type Mismatch".  In some cases I receive "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Watch screenprint of "rs"

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's `Fields` not `Items`...

Comment: Sorry I meant:
rs.Fields(1).Value
rs.Fields(1).Value(0)
rs.Fields(1).Value(0).text
rs.Fields(1).Value.Value(0)

Comment: You get "Type Mismatch" when the left hand side is not the same as right hand side.  Since the right hand side is Variant/String, then the left hand side also needs to be Variant.  If you can, go back to try the right hand side where you got Type Mismatch and use a proper left hand side.

Comment: Is this a multi-valued field? [Not a good idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461582/multivalued-fields-a-good-idea)

Comment: The left side is just a variable.  I also see the same error if I attempt "? rs.fields.item(1.Value" in the Intermediate window.

Also "? rs.fields(1).value(1)" in the Intermediate window produces the "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" response.

The text within "Value(0)" is not multi-valued.  It is a field in our Active Directory.

Comment: Did you find a way to access the value? Same issue here.