# VBA Accessing a nested value in record set

Tags: excel, vba

I am querying Active Directory from VBA which returns a recordset.

I access the values returned in the recordset "rs" per the code below:

```
Set rs = cmd.Execute
adUser.Add "givenName", rs.Fields("GivenName").Value
adUser.Add "sn", rs.Fields("sn").Value
```

However one of the returned values, has the result in a nested "value" and I can not work out how to access the returned value. The ObjectWatch shows it like this:

[image]

I tried:

```
rs.Fields("postOfficeBox").Value(Item(0))
```

The value returned I am trying to access is Variant/String.

Similar question here without answer: [VBA: Accessing Variant/String Array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122841/vba-accessing-variant-string-array-value)

Comment: Try `rs.Fields("postOfficeBox").Value.Value(0)`.    Left clicking the property will bring up a context menu that has an option to copy the property path.  It may help.  I would put a break after you load the dataset and fiddle with rs in the immediate window until i figured it out.  Good Luck

Comment: Please, put the code that you use to query active directory. I will try to reproduce your problem.